# multiple TypeErrors like: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and I'm trying to calculate a new column using multiple `np.where()`

It's something like this :

```
df['col_D'] = "condition_unknown"
df['col_D'] = np.where((df['col_A']==df['col_B']) & (df['col_C']==4), "Condition-4",
                            np.where((df['col_A']==df['col_B']) & (df['col_C']==3), "Condition-3",
                                     np.where(df['col_C']>=2, "Condition_2more",
                                              df['col_D'])))
```

so it's basically like multiple `if then elif`.
`col_A`and `col_b`are string objects and `col_C` is integer. I get this error :

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'
```

I have seen that it's because "&" is bitwise, so I tried replacing the "&" operator by `and` operator, but I now have this error :

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

So I don't know what to do now, do you have any ideas?

Comment: Are the strings just single characters? Or are they actual text?

Comment: Hmm... something like `(df['col_A']==df['col_B']) & (df['col_C']==4)` should join properly because the things being bitwise and-ed are series of booleans

Comment: Sounds like you've got some str data in column C. `'a'>=2` would give that kind of error in Python. Can you post the data you're using?

Comment: @ifly6 it actually worked, incredible thank you!